# How to use an array as a variable to filter in Strapi v4 GraphQL

Tags: graphql, strapi

First off, I've looked through a ton of Q&A on SO, Strapi Docs and Strapi forum and I have not found any relevant data.

I am trying to use an array as an variable in **GraphQL**. Since we can declare the variables as an array, I am assuming that this can be done.

My question is, how to use an array as a variable inside filters using **GraphQL**. No matter what I try, the playground is always returning an error.

This is my current (non working) code:

```bash
query GetItems ($categories: [String]){
  myCollection(filters:
    { categories:
        {category:
          {containsi: $categories} //[$categories] does not work neither 
        }
    }
  ) {
        data{id}
  }
}
```

```json
{
  "categories": ["Work", "Leisure"]
}
```